# Name for numbers with a single non-zero digit.

Tags: terminology, number-systems

Given a base, is there a name for the numbers (positive or negative) that have only a single non-zero digit?

For example:

- Decimal: 4000, -30, 0.0008
- Binary: 1000
- Base 5: 300, -0.1

Contrived example sentence: "Subtracting 1 from any _____ decimal number $\geq$ 10 will yield a result that ends with the digit 9."

I guess, in general, a one-word name for all base-$n$ numbers $jn^k$ where $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $j\neq0$.

Comment: A unit multiple of a power of the base?